# Перевод предложения с русского на анлгийский на php?

Tags: php

Задачка простая: нужно перевести предложение с русского на английский, используя PHP и может какие-то сервисы.

Comment: Я думаю проще будет использовать какие-либо исходники, так как переводчики - это не так просто, как кажется)

Comment: я дико извиняюсь... *перевести* или все же *транслитировать*? Ибо перевод это не такая уж и тривиальная задачка

Comment: IMHO, откровенно говоря, машинный перевод **отдельных предложений** это профанация, если не брать случай, когда эти "предложения" заранее перечислены.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

к сожалению google прикрыл свою api, но можно воспользоваться от microsoft документация здесь: [ms translator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576287.aspx)

Comment: Дасобственно нашел уже  пример, спасибо. http://seazo.net/texts/perevod-s-pomoscyu-bing-translation-api.html

Answer (score 1):

а если использовать http://translate.google.ru/
?
ответ то этот сервис дает в виде html, а слово (предложение) можно давать через GET